# Unable to change __class__ of PySide.QtGui objects

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside

I've used PyQt4 quite a lot - sometimes I like to overload some of the objects to allow me to add some functionality. This works fine in PyQt4, eg:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
button = QtGui.QPushButton()
class MyPushButton(QtGui.QPushButton): pass
button.__class__ = MyPushButton
```

However, I'm trying to adapt some of my code so that it uses PySide instead of PyQt4. My understanding is that they should have the same functionality. PySide will not allow me to do the same thing.

```
from PySide import QtGui
button = QtGui.QPushButton()
class MyPushButton(QtGui.QPushButton): pass
button.__class__ = MyPushButton
```

This errors with:

```
TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types
```

Is there another way I can change the class of my object to avoid this error? I'm not really sure what's causing it.

*NOTE: I need to change the class of the object after it is created as the object is created in a library which is compiled by pyuic. Also my PySide installation does not have the uic module.*

Answer (score 3):

PySide uses [Shiboken](http://shiboken.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to generate the CPython bindings for Qt from
its C++ classes. All of the Qt python classes such as `QPushButton` are
implemented in C++ which is why you cannot overwrite `__class__`.

```
>>> button = QPushButton()
>>> button.__class__ = MyButton
TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types
```

According to the Shiboken's documentation, you can [monkey patch (or duck punch)](http://shiboken.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wordsofadvice.html#duck-punching-and-virtual-methods)
the methods on an already instantiated object so long as the methods are
virtual (overridable):

```
import types

def override_text(self):
    return 'overridden'

# Bind override_text() to button.
button.text = types.MethodType(override_text, button, QPushButton)
```

Taking this further you can sub-class `QPushButton` as `MyButton`, and
dynamically inject the methods from `MyButton` into the `QPushButton`
instance. Making `MyButton` a sub-class of `QPushButton` is purely
optional, but would allow you to make your own instances of `MyButton`
in addition to the modified `QPushButton` instances.

Let's define `MyButton` as a sub-class of `QPushButton`.

```
class MyButton(QPushButton):

    def text(self):
        # This will override QPushButton's text() method.
        print("inside MyButton.text()")
        return QPushButton.text(self)
```

- NOTE: You have to use the old-style of calling parent class methods.
  `super()` fails with a `TypeError` because self is actually a `QPushButton`
  and not a `MyButton` when the method is injected.

Or if you wanted to take more of a mixin approach, let's define `MyButtonOverrides`:

```
class MyButtonOverrides(object):

    def text(self):
        # This will override QPushButton's text() method.
        print("inside MyButtonOverrides.text()")
        return self.__class__.text(self)
```

- NOTE: You can call the `QPushButton.text()` directly through `self.__class__`
  because you won't be using `MyButtonOverrides` directly.

Now let's define `extend_instance()` which will inject your override
methods from `MyButton` (or `MyButtonOverrides`) into the `QPushButton`
instance:

```
import inspect

def extend_instance(obj, cls):
    for name, attr in vars(cls).items():
        if inspect.isroutine(attr):
            # Bind instance, class and static methods to *obj*.
            setattr(obj, name, attr.__get__(obj, obj.__class__))
```

If you'd like your class methods to remain bound to their originating class
(e.g., `MyButton`) then use the following:

```
def extend_instance(obj, cls):
    for name, attr in vars(cls).items():
        if inspect.isroutine(attr):
            if isinstance(attr, classmethod):
                # Bind class methods to *cls*.
                setattr(obj, name, attr.__get__(cls, cls))
            else:
                # Bind instance and static methods to *obj*.
                setattr(obj, name, attr.__get__(obj, obj.__class__))
```

Through my testing this works in Python 2.7 and 3.3, but should
work on 2.6+ and 3+.

Finally to modify the button, use `extend_instance()`.

```
>>> button = QPushButton()
>>> extend_instance(button, MyButton)
>>> button.text()
inside MyButton.text()
u''
```

Answer (score 1):

Monkey-patching `__class__` is completely unnecessary. Instead, you should [promote](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets) the relevant widgets in Qt Designer so that they automatically use your subclass.

To do this, in Qt Designer, right-click the widget and select "Promote to...". In the dialog, set "Promoted class name" to your subclass (e.g. "MyPushButton"), and set "Header file" to the python import path for the module containing the subclass (e.g. "myapp", or "myapp.gui", or whatever).

Now click "Add", and then "Promote", and you will see the class change from "QPushButton" to "MyPushButton" in the Object Inspector pane.

When you re-generate your ui module with `pyuic` or `pyside-uic`, it will contain code like this:

```
class Ui_Window(object):
    def setupUi(self, Window):
        ...
        self.button = MyPushButton(Window)
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        ...

from myapp import MyPushButton
```

So the promoted button will be created as an instance of `MyPushButton`, and there is no longer any need to hack `__class__`.

This technique of promoting widgets will work for both PyQt and PySide.

Comment: My function receives an already instantiated Widget and I need to "promote" widgets programmatically. I do not have control over the creation of the Widget. Monkey-patch seems necessary.

Comment: @Hernan. Rather than adding extra conditions every time someone offers a solution, it would be better if you made it clear in your question exactly what your requirements are.

Comment: @cpburnz. The OP actually said: "...as the object is created in a library which is compiled by pyuic". Which suggested to me that the problem _was a result of_ the objects being created by pyuic. He also did not mention not having control over the creation of the objects. But whatever, I'm not going to delete my answer as it will probably still help some people who are searching on this general topic.

Comment: @ekhumoro I agree with cpburnz. The question is quite clear to me. My understanding of "... the object is created in a library ..." is that you do not control that library. It also gives an example of the code that does not work in PySide. That is how I understood the question (which is not mine!) and the reason why I offered a bounty.

Comment: @Hernan. Apologies: I completely missed that you weren't the OP - if that wasn't obvious by now!

Comment: @ekhumoro. No problem! and do not delete your answer. I think your answer is the right one when you control the full thing.