# Python: Change class type with decorator and keep it's methods

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pyqt, decorator

I want to create a class which could be used inside different Applications and their APIs to create UIs. Therefor I created a module called *ui.py*. Inside this module is the following:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui


def CreateGui(uiFile, parent=None):
    print "Ui build.."

def GetUiObject(uiClass):
    pUI = uiClass.PARENT
    class ParentUI(pUI):
        def __init__(self, uiFile):
            CreateGui(uiFile, self)
        def __call__(self, cls):
            for func in uiClass.__dict__:
                setattr(cls, func, uiClass.__dict__[func])
    return ParentUI

@GetUiObject
class UI(object):
    PARENT = QtGui.QMainWindow

    def __init__(self, uiFile):
        CreateGui(uiFile)
```

Inside my pipeline module module, which is used by the application:

```
from ui import UI

UI.PARENT = QtGui.QWidget

class Tool_UI(UI):
    def __init__(self, uiFile):
        super(Tool_UI, self).__init__(uiFile)
        print "In Application"


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
A = Tool_UI("C:/test/testUi.ui")
A.CreateGui()
```

But I get the following Error:

```
Ui build..
In Application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test/maxUi.py", line 13, in <module>
    A.CreateGui()
RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type Tool_UI was never called
```

What do I wrong?

**EDIT:**

[cpburnz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369450/cpburnz) answers why the code is erroring, but it is still not working.
I want to replace the class with another one which has a different base. I opened a new question with a better description of my problem and different solutions I tried ([How to rebase or dynamically replace a class with a different base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413046/python-how-to-rebase-or-dynamically-replace-a-class-with-a-different-base-class)).

Comment: What the heck is that code supposed to do? What problem is it intended to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks related to [Python: RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of %S was never called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12280371/369450) but your setup is kind of different so I'll extrapolate to make it more clear.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test/maxUi.py", line 13, in <module>
    A.CreateGui()
RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type Tool_UI was never called
```

This means somewhere in the class hierarchy for `Tool_UI` that `super(...).__init__(...)`
is not being called. This appears to be raised by `QObject` or `QWidget`.
Looking at the class defined in `GetUiObject()`, there is no call to the super's init
even though the parent class `pUI` is `QWidget`. You most likely need to add
a call to the super init there:

```
def GetUiObject(uiClass):
    pUI = uiClass.PARENT

    class ParentUI(pUI):

        def __init__(self, uiFile):
            super(ParentUI, self).__init__() # <-- Missing.
            CreateGui(uiFile, self)

        def __call__(self, cls):
            for func in uiClass.__dict__:
                setattr(cls, func, uiClass.__dict__[func])

    return ParentUI
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I was getting code blind after hours of trying to solve this problem.

Comment: the error is gone, but the problem is not solved. Please look at my edit. Do you have any solution for my problem?

Comment: @MagSec I don't know if this will help but trying to override `__class__` in your follow-up question looks roughly related to [Unable to change \_\_class__ of PySide.QtGui objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10707618/369450).

Comment: I don't think that this is working, because PySide is using [Shiboken](http://shiboken.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and PyQt not. So they will be still incompatible. To  do a Monkey Patch I need to predefine each base to a class and That's not what I want to do inside this module