# Python: How to rebase or dynamically replace a class with a different base class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to create a common class which I want to use inside different applications.

> The idea: a class which could be used as a base class for ui creations. This class will be based to a widget of the applications in it's specific gui system (PySide, or PyQt)

This would allow me to follow the same code flow to generate gui's. I like to have same structures inside my pipeline and it makes it much easier to work in different applications with the same commands.

> The problem: PyQt and PySide are compiled in C++ and do not follow the Python class structure

I tried a lot of different things to get it to work, but every time I got stock at some point and doesn't get the result I want.

1. Try (rebase):

   in this try I used `__class__` to rebase the class itself.

   ```python
   from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

   class UiMainBase(object):
       PARENT = QtGui.QMainWindow
       def __init__(self, uiFile=None, parent=None):
           if parent: self.PARENT = parent
           self.__class__ = self.PARENT


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       import sys
       from PySide import QtGui as PySideGui

       class MyGui(UiMainBase):
           def __init__(self, uiFile):
               super(MyGui, self).__init__(uiFile, PySideGui.QMainWindow)

       Ui = r"C:\pythonTest\ui\test.ui"
       app = PySideGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
       win = MyGui(Ui)
       win.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

> The errors I get are reasonable and doesn't has to be explained.

```python
    # 1st Error :
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      #[..]
      File "C:/pythonTest/ui/ui.py", line 18, in __init__
        self.__class__ = self.PARENT
    TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types

    # 2nd Error (without parsing the parent
    # argument to __init__ of super in MyGui) :
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      #[..]
      File "C:/pythonTest/ui/uiTest.py", line 18, in __init__
        self.__class__ = self.PARENT
    TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'MyGui' object layout differs from 'QMainWindow'
```

2. Try (rebase):

   in this try I used `__bases__` to rebase the class itself.

   ```python
   from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

   class UiMainBase(object):
       PARENT = QtGui.QMainWindow
       def __init__(self, uiFile=None, parent=None):
           if parent: self.PARENT = parent
           self.__bases__= (self.PARENT,)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       import sys
       from PySide import QtGui as PySideGui

       class MyGui(UiMainBase):
           def __init__(self, uiFile):
               super(MyGui, self).__init__(uiFile, PySideGui.QMainWindow)

       Ui = r"C:\pythonTest\ui\test.ui"
       app = PySideGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
       win = MyGui(Ui)
       print win.__bases__ # <- shows what base the object has
       win.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

> In this result, we can see that the object now get's the right base, but don't get it's methods and variables (not even if I call `super` after setting `__bases__`).

```python
    <type 'PySide.QtGui.QMainWindow'> # <- the base
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/pythonTest/ui/uiTest.py", line 34, in <module>
        win.show()
    AttributeError: 'MyGui' object has no attribute 'show'
```

3. Try (decorator) :

   instead of rebase an object I tried to replace the class with another one that has the right base

   ```python
   from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


   def GetUiObject(uiClass):
       parentWidget = uiClass.PARENT # <- Gets the original value, 
                                     # not the latest, why?
       class ParentUI(parentWidget, uiClass):
           def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
               super(ParentUI, self).__init__()
               uiClass.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
               #[..]
           def __call__(self, cls):
               for func in uiClass.__dict__:
                   setattr(cls, func, uiClass.__dict__[func])
       #ParentUI = type("ParentUI", (parentWidget,),ParentUI.__dict__.copy())
       return ParentUI

   @GetUiObject
   class UiMainBase( object ):
       PARENT = QtGui.QMainWindow
       def __init__(self, uiFile=None, *args, **kwargs):
           """constructor.."""
           #[..]



   if __name__ == "__main__":
       import sys
       from PySide import QtGui as PySideGui

       UiMainBase.PARENT = PySideGui.QMainWindow # <- specify the application
                                                 # ui architecture as parent

       class MyGui(UiMainBase):
           def __init__(self, uiFile=None): 
               # This variant of base class definition doesn't allow parsing
               # the parent argument with with it
               # (__init__ will be executed after base is set)
               super(MyGui, self).__init__(uiFile=None)
               print self.menuBar () # <- check used ui architecture
   ```

> Th e result of this variant doesn't error and prints: `<PyQt4.QtGui.QMenuBar object at 0x00000000021C9D38>`, but `MyGui` is not based to `PySideGui.QMainWindow` like I expected

**EDIT:**

> *Why do not defining classes with a base of `PySide` and one with a base of `PyQt4`?:*

Because I want to leave it open for a genral use and later extensions. It should be free to set a parent widget, which is defined by the application (`PySide` or `PyQt`). But each application has it's own method or function to get it's MainWindow. So if you want extend some widgets of this MainWindow, or just parent a new ui to it you need to define it as the parent, or directly base from it. Some applications and it's API's do not support a free generated ui from type `PySide.QtGui.QMainWindow`  or `PyQt4.QtGui.QMainWindow`. That's the main reason I was trying to do it in this way. Of course I could create a `UiMainWindow` class for each application and base it to it's main window (this is what I do for now), but I was trying to make it more generic and global for my pipeline API.

**Example of usage:**

This example is for 3DS-Max and inside a module of it's pipeline integration.

```
from pythonLibrary.file import Path 
from qtLibrary.ui import UiMainBase
from blurdev.gui import Window

UiMainBase.PARENT = Window
class UiWidget( UiMainBase ):
    """
    This class creates a widget which is parented
    to the PySide implementation of blur's Python
    in 3DS-Max
    """
    def __init__(self, uiFile=None):
        super(UiWidget, self).__init__()
        if uiFile: self.loadUi(uiFile, self)
        self.show()
    #[..]

class PublishUi(UiWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        uiFile = Path.Combine(__file__,self.__class__.__name__+".ui")
        super(PublishUi, self).__init__(uiFile)

    #[..]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This should be called from a menu entry inside 3DS-Max
    publishWindow = PublishUi()
```

Does anyone has a solution for this situation?

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but why don't you use a factory pattern?

Comment: Why not just define two different versions of `UiMainBase`, each with the correct parent, then choose the correct one as the parent for `MyGui`?

Comment: @chepner: please read my edit. I hope that makes it a bit more clear why I trying to do this in this way

Comment: @matino: The decorator variant I tried is a kind of Factory Pattern method, but I don't want to call a method to get my class. I want to that the class could be imported and set as a base in every gui class I am using. I just give it a pearent and it automatically changes/or recreate itsel with the needed base.

Comment: @MagSec. Sorry, but this is even harder to follow than your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29368372/984421) on this topic. However, one obvious code-smell is that all your examples import both PyQt *and* PySide. Any application/library that does that is fundamentally broken right from the start. The place to choose the GUI toolkit is at *import time*, not at *class creation time*. AFAICT, what you really want is a toolkit abstraction layer: i.e. something like [QtPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/QtPy/).

Comment: @ekhumoro: I only import both in my example to show what I mean. I just trying to generate a library for my pipeline which I could use in any application. I will never import both packages, I just needed an example code to show what I mean. You could also create two different classes and try two do this instead of using PyQt and PySide if you feel better

Comment: @MagSec. Well, thing is, I still don't understand what "this" is. It seems obvious why the third example doesn't work, though. The decorator has already replaced `UiMainBase` with `ParentUI` by the time `PARENT` is reset, so it couldn't possibly have any affect on the creation of the *class* (or any instances created from it). But anyway: why doesn't a toolkit abstraction layer solve your problem? How would your solution differ from it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change base class of instances at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/how-to-dynamically-change-base-class-of-instances-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a factory function which dynamically generates the correct base class. In real life, you'd probably memoize the factory so that it always returns the same class object for a given parent, rather than creating multiple identical classes.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

def BaseFactory(parent):

    class UiMainBase(parent):
        ....

    return UiMainBase

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PySide import QtGui as PySideGui

    # UiMainBase = BaseFactory(QtGui.QMainWindow)
    UiMainBase = BaseFactory(PySideGui.QMainWindow)
    class MyGui(UiMainBase):
        ...

    Ui = r"C:\pythonTest\ui\test.ui"
    app = PySideGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyGui(Ui)
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, but as a decorator.

Comment: You don't want a decorator, since you don't want to edit an existing class; you want to define the class with the correct base in the first place. The difference is `decorator(Class(FixedBase))` (changing the grandparent after the fact) vs `Class(BaseFactory(CorrectGrandparent))` (using the right grandparent from the beginning).

Comment: A decorator could replace the class you are calling. That's what my decorator is doing. It is just not taking the updated constant variable `PARENT`. If you change inside the decorator `GetUiObject` the first line to `parentWidget = PySideGui.QMainWindow` and put the import of `PySideGui` on the top of the module, you will see that the print of `QMenuBar` is now a PySide object. So it is replacing the class itself with a new class and the specified base